# Export data from Google Datastore to Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore, etl

What is the best way or ETL process in python to export data from Google Cloud Datastore to Google Bigquery? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

See https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities for details about exporting datastore entities to GCS, as well as a pointer to ingesting said backups into BigQuery.